# i was making a simple reactiveform in angular bt when i am importing formcontrol it is showing error in running

Tags: angular

[see the above image thi is occiring again and again and my ide is not showing any red errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNRpW.png)

I was trying to run my form but this error keeps occuring again and again i have even imported formGroup ,Formcontrol ,reactiveformmodule too

Comment: Can you show code of the imports?

Comment: Those imports are the imports of a standalone component or module. You already imported the ReactiveFormsModule and the FormsModule, you don't need this FormControl import.